# remove last character with sub regex call

Tags: python, regex

Try to remove the last "," of each line but current logic only remove the last one:

```
import re

x = """
A,B,C,
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9,
"""
x = re.sub(",$","",x,re.MULTILINE)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
A,B,C,
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9
```

expected output:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Comment: The fourth argument in the `re.sub()` method is "count" specifying how many replacements to make. You supplied `re.MULTILINE` for the count which doesn't make much sense. Both answers below show the correct way to supply the arguments you need (using named arguments or by supplying `0` for the count in the 4th argument position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it:

```
import re

x = """
A,B,C,
1,2,3,
4,5,6,
7,8,9,
"""
# regix to remove all commas at the end of each line
x = re.sub(r',$', '', x, flags=re.M)
# '$', means the end of the line
# '', means replace with nothing
# x, os the string to be searched
# flags=re.M, means to search the whole string, not just the first line
# flags=re.MULTILINE does the same job
print(x)
```

output->

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Comment: Your answer would have significantly more value if you explained how you changed the code, and why.

Answer (score 4):

```
re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

flag is 5th argument.